# Formatted xticklabels on pandas plot show as 1971

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, datetime, xticks

I've imported data from an Excel file and I plot it with Matplotlib. If I use only default settings I get accurate results with correct tick labels, even if not formatted the way I want.

```
df.plot()
```

[image: default plot]

But trying to use ConciseDateFormatter yields bizarre results

```
ax=df.plot()
locator = mdates.AutoDateLocator(minticks=5, maxticks=10)
formatter = mdates.ConciseDateFormatter(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(locator)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

[image: odd output]

ConciseDateFormatter makes some odd decisions here, including tagging the whole date series as 'October 1971'. The data actually spans from Feb 2021 through Sep 2023. Note that this is not the '1970' problem that others have asked about. 1970 and 1971 are different years.

The big question: why is it selecting and displaying this weird date, and how can I fix it?

The smaller question: how do I get it to display only month names and, where appropriate, years, replacing those random numbers on the x-axis in some locations?

Comment: you have more than 10 ticks so maxticks should be a bigger number I think, like 100 [or more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26382075/2834978)

Comment: @LMC that makes it weirder — the '1971-Oct' tag is still in the lower right, and the x-axis tags become 'oct' and the days of the (incorrect) months of September and October 1971.

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. Update pandas and matplotlib. See [code and plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J1kKs.png)

Comment: In terms of xtick locations and corresponding dates, 18628 corresponds to 2021, whereas 0 corresponds to 1970. `print(ax.get_xticklabels())`.